Powerautomate Escapes all characters in my Array. That way its not usable as E-mail Attachment
I´m trying to send multiple E-mail Attachements via Powerautomate.
I prepare Content by creating an Array just like E-mail Attachements usually are formed. But when i want to use this array powerautomate Escapes all my Characters:
"emailMessage/Attachments": "{ "Name": File0.dotx,\n  "ContentBytes": {\n    "$content-type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-
That way it can´t be interpreted correctly and if i try to use the json() function it also does not work.
Help anyone?
I even tried manually building a string out of the array that can be used. But it still did not work.

If that’s in fact the exact json then it’s malformed, \n is just a line break, the json() function will work with those characters. You’re missing quotes in that.

I would recommend using a compose action to put together your json that you eventually  pass to the email action.
Then to remove the escape characters you can just do:
json(replace(string(your compose output),'\n',''))


Thanks for your Answer i think i already tried something similar, but i'll try again and let you know. :)

I tried solving this, and the conversion JSON helped however, now only the first Attachements finds its way into the E-mail the Subsequent attachements dissapear after i convert the String to JSON, probably powerautomate Interpets the String as an Object to work with after the conversion to JSON, since it also has a "Name" Field etc.
Filestring before Json Conversion
Filestring after Json Conversion
